# Android Camera Flash Control

Tags: android, android-camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Turn on only Camera flash light programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

okay guys, I have been looking for a little while and I cant seem to find this anywhere, I would like to grant my camera application access to the flash bulbs or whatever you want to call them, If anyone knows and would like to share that would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone can point me into the right direction that would be great.

Comment: What sort of 'access' do you mean could you explain what you want to do with the flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this...

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

you need to grant permission to use the camera *and* use the `<uses-feature>` for camera features you want to use:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

The features supported are here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

and the camera ones you want are

```
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.hardware.camera.flash
```

Comment: yeah i have that but i cant figure out how to set the state of the flash... ive been to that page before...

Comment: You can visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html to set the state of the flash. Depending on hardware, it supports AUTO, off, on, red eye, and torch.