# switch on / off flash light programmatically on android smartphones (without using the camera)

Tags: android

I saw your question about [How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)"How Turn on only Camera flash light programmatically in android?".
I'm trying to do the same.

The links you used to solve your problem seem to be out of order: http://code.google.com/p/quick-settings/

Could you share your solution ?

I have another question: is there a way to see in the emulator whether the flash light is on or off ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have updated the answer with link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android/6069503#6069503