# Check my android has flashlight

Tags: android-camera, flashlight, camera-flash

how can i check that my Android Device have camera flashlight?
If Code so where should i put that to check my device flash availability.
Tell me please every way to check and How can i open it.
I have Android `COCA Pierre alps P5000` MTK Device.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android):

For Checking availability of flash in device:

You can use the following

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)
```

Comment: @user3086932 you ask me? You should write it where you want to check for this feature.