# How to turn on/off android flashlight every x second?

Tags: android

Here is my code.Please help me i want turn on/off every x second.How can i make it?Please give me idea.

Im calling turn on/off codes with Methods.
I tried loops but didnt work.
Here is my code.Please help me i want turn on/off every x second.How can i make it?Please give me idea.

Im calling turn on/off codes with Methods.
I tried loops but didnt work.

```
 package com.example.arama;

  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
  import android.hardware.Camera;
  import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
  import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Toast;

  public class GelenArama extends BroadcastReceiver{
private Camera cmobj;
private Intent intent;
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
Parameters p = cmobj.getParameters();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

         String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

         if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {

             flashCalistir();




             // Your Code
        }

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {

                 // Your Code
        }

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
        {

         flashDurdur();

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }





        }   




    public void flashCalistir(){
        cmobj=Camera.open();
        Parameters p = cmobj.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cmobj.setParameters(p);
        cmobj.startPreview();

    }

    public void flashDurdur(){
        cmobj=Camera.open();
        Parameters p = cmobj.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cmobj.setParameters(p);
        cmobj.stopPreview();
        cmobj.release();
    }




   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer describes how to turn the light on in lots of detail. [How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

To turn it off and on, you could use a Timer and TimerTask.