# How to check if the flashlight is on?

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there any way to check once you have tried to turn the flashlight on if it has worked or not?

I'm using:

```
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

To turn the camera on. This works with most phones, but not with all phones so I need to know if it's worked or not.

Edit: Just to be clear, I need to know if turning the flash on has actually worked or not. Sometimes you need to use FLASH_MODE_ON instead of FLASH_MODE_TRUE, and sometimes you need to use FLASH_MODE_ON even when

```
List<String> flashModes = p.getSupportedFlashModes();
flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
```

returns true.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check out this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Comment: hi the answer is given please have a look and visit http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/ for more

Comment: @InnocentKiller Thanks, I have looked at that link before, but I can't see a way there that lets you know if turning the light on has worked or not.

Comment: @Jitesh Upadhyay Thanks for the reply but please read my question, I asked if there is any way to check if turning the light on actually worked or not.

Comment: yeah !! i deleted the previous answer, will try to get and willl be back to you

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for a solution for a while and just can't find anything. Just to make it clear to anyone else I need a way to check if the torch has actually turned on or not as FLASH_MODE_TORCH doesn't work with all phones. When it doesn't work the torch just doesn't turn on. This is sometimes the case even when flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH) comes back as true.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if the device supports flashlight:

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Then you can safely assume that it will be turned on when you start preview.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't always seem to work, some phones need to use FLASH_MODE_ON instead.

Comment: This is to check if the device has flash mode available.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
camera.getParameters().getFlashMode().equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
```

Returns `true` flashlight is on

Note: `Camera` class has been deprecated in API level 21. so this solution won't work for recent versions