# Using python and kivy for andoride

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to build an android app.
And I am going to use kivy.
So,I was wondering if there is a package that can support android function (as accessing the flashlight) next to kivy. Or if there is another package rather than kivy that can do these stuff.

Comment: `andoride`? Is this a spelling mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoclass which is part of pyjnius (from jnius import autoclass).

[Accessing android flashlight(camera LED flash) with kivy/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111643/accessing-android-flashlightcamera-led-flash-with-kivy-python)