# Turn Camera flashlist on/off from service in Android

Tags: java, android, service

I created an android service which creates a circle on Window.manager using canvas, and on touching that circle I want to turn the flashlight on/off.

I am able to turn the flashlist on but app crashes when I touch again to turn it off.

```
public void torch(int val){
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "CameraInstance", e);
    }
    if(val == 1) {
        if (camera != null) {
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (camera != null){
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
    }
}
}
else if(evtouchpossitiondownX >= XH && evtouchpossitiondownX < (XH + WH)
                                                  && evtouchpossitiondownY >= YH && evtouchpossitiondownY < (YH + HH)) {
                                              //Homescreen
                                             /* Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                              startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                              startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                              startActivity(startMain);*/
                                              process.torch(1);

                                              windowManager.removeView(control_cirlce);
                                              windowManager.addView(floatingFaceBubble, myParams);
```

I am getting

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>               at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:497)
>               at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:357)
>               at com.amlpl.laziapp.Bubdub.processor.torch(processor.java:123)
>               at com.amlpl.laziapp.Bubdub.laziservice$3.onTouch(laziservice.java:255)
>               at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8387)
>               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8583)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4091)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3957)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3638)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5806)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5745)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5716)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
>               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
Maybe try checking if your camera object has been initialized before calling open. Maybe calling `Camera.open();` when the camera is already open is causing the error.

```
if(camera == null){
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "CameraInstance", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes camera object is already initialized in the beginning of class declaration

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the camera permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Yes I have already added   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 static Camera camera = null;
```

and

```
try{ 
       if(clickOn == true) {
       clickOn = false;
       camera = Camera.open();
       Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
       parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
       camera.setParameters(parameters);
       camera.startPreview();

   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button1, View.GONE);
   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button2, View.VISIBLE);
   localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
   } else {
   clickOn = true;
   camera.stopPreview();
   camera.release();
   camera = null;

   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button1, View.VISIBLE);
   remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button2, View.GONE);
   localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
   }    
   }catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e("Error", ""+e);}
```

For more check [link!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I already tried this but its not working I am calling this method thought a service.

Comment: what exactly error/exception you are getting ,,, update the details in logcat