# how can I turn on the camera flash for specific duration in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight

[How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

my question us a variation of the above one
i want to specifically set the duration for turning on the flash the value of which is found on runtime

is there any way to do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a tutorial for building a flashlight android application: [android flashlight tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/)

I think the following lines may prove helpful to you:

"Turning on flashlight can be done by setting camera flash mode to FLASH_MODE_TORCH. The following two functions getCamera() and turnOnFlash() will do that for us. Add these functions to your [activity]"

To turn off the flash by setting the camera flash mode to "FLASH_MODE_OFF"

The code for the 'getCamera()' and 'turnOnFlash()' functions can be found by following the link above.. So, I urge you to follow the link and check out the code samples they've posted in steps 8 and 9, they should help you to get the light turning on and off programmatically.

Next, in order to get the code to run on a specific time interval you can implement a runnable to turn the flashlight off a specific amount of time after it was turned on.

Here is an example of how to run the turnOffFlash() function (or whatever you have called it) with a delay.

```java
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            turnOffFlash();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Replace 10000 with your delay in millis.

Comment: any way other than implementing a runnable??

Comment: If you want to turn it on for a specific amount of time (like X seconds) I think you have to use a runnable. But don't let that deter you! I have edited my answer with an example of how to use a handler/runnable to run your function with a delay.