# Android Camera (Flashlight) API too slow

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-camera

I making a Flashlight app, and I use Fragments.
When I press the button, The lantern light delayed more than 4 seconds, and i don't know what happen.
Also, when I Press the switch button another time, the Flashlight doesn't turn off
Any idea?

Also I would like to make a stroboscopic lantern light with another button.

I search in internet but i dont find another option to make this feature, only this.

this is my code

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class HerramientasFragment extends Fragment {

  private Camera cam;
  private Switch linterna;

  public HerramientasFragment() {
      // Required empty public constructor
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      cam = Camera.open();
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View masterView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herramientas, container, false);
      linterna = (Switch) masterView.findViewById(R.id.switch_linterna);
      linterna.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Switch liternaSwitch = (Switch) v;

            Parameters p;

            if (liternaSwitch.isChecked()) {
                p = cam.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
            } else {
                p = cam.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.stopPreview();
            }

        }
    });

    return masterView;
}

}
```

Comment: What device are you testing on? Does the delay happen on other camera apps too?

Comment: I am testing in a GALAXY S4, and I downloaded another app and the flashlight is very fast does not delay

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the 4 second delay is hardware/operating system related and out of your control. That's not to say it can't be fixed, but I am unable to find anything related to it (Some Android experts might have a better idea here).

The light not turning off is probably because you need to add `cam.release();` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069503/5117760).

As for a stroboscopic light, I found [this tutorial](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/01/android-torch-app-with-stroboscopic.html). It seems to be almost exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I've been looking around a lot, and I have been unable to find anything related to slow camera startup. I hope that my answer helps with your other issues though.

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the line `cam.startPreview()` worked for me .

```
public void flashLightOn(){
     p = cam.getParameters();
     p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
     cam.setParameters(p);
}

public void flashLightOff(){
     p = cam.getParameters();
     p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
     cam.setParameters(p);
}
```