# Android Turn on Flashlight Across ALL Versions of Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight, android-camera2

I've been working on an app that needs to turn the flashlight on and off on an Android phone.  I need a way to turn on the flashlight across ALL versions of Android above API 15.  The problem is, on older phones (API < 21), I have to use the traditional way (below).  But on newer phones, like my Nexus 6P, I have to use the Camera2 interface (below the below).  Is there one way to have the flashlight torch work on ALL versions of Android with one set of code?

Below:

```
camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();

camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.stopPreview();
// camera.release();  used later when app closes
```

Below the Below:

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, state);  // state is either true or false
```

Comment: I see that the calls are deprecated, but not unusable. Could you not use the traditional way for all devices?

Comment: For some reason, no.  My Nexus 6P doesn't work when using the normal API.  The Android Monitor outputs: `E/Camera: Error 2`.  I have looked up this error before with no help.  Is there a list of camera errors somewhere or does the original API just not work?

Comment: perhaps the answer here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557157/android-flashlight-code-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to segment different sdk versions during runtime to determine which method to choose:

```
    private final int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //do old way
    } else {
        //do new way
    }
```

More information here: [How to support multiple android version in your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552250/how-to-support-multiple-android-version-in-your-code)

Comment: I've used that but Samsung phones don't support Camera2 even if they have a 21+ API version.  It also slows down code using a try/catch statement.

Comment: But how API < 21?