# Android Fail to Connect to Camera Service?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am making an app that needs to use the camera flash.  My code will be below this post, but I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` when I try to open the camera.  The error comes when the `Camera.open();` method is called.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

I have tried restarting the phone, closing all apps, and I still get the same error.

Is there a way to release/close the camera before opening it?  I don't know how you would close a null object.

Screen orientation is not a problem as the app is only allowed vertical orientation.

The default camera app works, but not this app.

Error (Full):

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:319)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:292)
        at com.bensuniverse.flashlightx.processes.CameraHandler.toggleFlash(CameraHandler.java:21)
        at com.bensuniverse.flashlightx.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17052)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try and declare the camera before you try and open it, as follow: static Camera camera = null

Comment: Have you added the required permissions in the manifest? Can you post the stack trace? Logcat output?

Comment: All permissions are added, as I am using Camera2 on my Nexus 6P with no problems.  I am using my old phone for backwards compatibility.  I updated the post with the full error.  There is nothing major in the logcat above that.

Comment: If your device "lost" the camera and cannot open the stock camera app, you simply reboot the phone. If another app can open camera, you probably forgot to call camera.release()

Comment: How can I call `camera.release()` before I open the camera?  The normal camera app works, and the app still crashes on a fresh phone restart.

Comment: One case could be that your activity swithes orientation while starting. The good practice is to keep Camera object as a *field* of your Activity class.

Comment: The app already only stays in vertical orientation, though.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are releasing the camera object properly. If you are trying to reopen camera object if already opened then it will get crashed with the error mentioned by you in stack trace:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();  

// Stop camera preview and release it.
camera.stopPreview();
camera.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue , reason was my another  app uses the camera. but i forget to release the resources in that app. so don't forget to release resources when the app about to close. (onStop / onDestroy()).
Camera hardware is a shared resource that must be carefully managed so your application does not collide with other applications that may also want to use it.