# Android - Camera2 : The easiest way to turn on the torch light

Tags: android, torch, camera2

The simplest way to turn on the torch light was :

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

The simplest way to turn it off was :

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.stopPreview();
```

But, as the Camera class is now deprecated, what is the easiest way to achieve the same result with the Camera2 class? I only found long and complicated solutions...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#setTorchMode(java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: Seriously @user0815. The official documentation link? Come on... :p

Answer (score 2):

check the answer from Daniel Netzer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699273/android-turn-on-off-camera-flash-programatically-with-camera2)
you just need to write 3 line to turn on torch

```
CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0]; // Usually front camera is at 0 position and back camera is 1.
camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

Comment: A lot more code is required to activate the Flash. :|

Comment: Note that setTorchMode is available from API level 23+