# Android API Level 16 and higher Torch App

Tags: android, camera, torch, flashlight

I found this Question but it doesn't work for me. (Nothing happens. Tested on Wiko Rainbow Jam)
[Android - Camera2 : The easiest way to turn on the torch light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482014/android-camera2-the-easiest-way-to-turn-on-the-torch-light)

My App have to run on min. API Level 16! Is there an `SupportCameraManager` or an Library (under Apache), which can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** The problem was that I only got the camera's parameters when turning on the light and turning off the light. This must apparently also be done in the constructor or in the overwriting onStart method.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    camera = Camera.open(); //Also Call this
    params = camera.getParameters(); //and this, in the Constructor
}
```

as fields:

```
private Camera camera;
Parameters params;
```

And then you can start the flashlight with these snippets of code: [Android - Camera2 : The easiest way to turn on the torch light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482014/android-camera2-the-easiest-way-to-turn-on-the-torch-light)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use [this](https://github.com/Abhi347/NoobCameraFlash).

Initialize the NoobCameraManager singleton.

```
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().init(this);
```

You can optionally set the Log Level for debug logging. Logging uses LumberJack library. The default LogLevel is LogLevel.None

```
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().init(this, LogLevel.Verbose);
```

After that you just need to call the singleton to turn on or off the camera flash.

```
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().turnOnFlash();
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().turnOffFlash();
```

You can take care of the runtime permission to access Camera yourself or can allow the library to do it for you

```
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().takePermissions();
```

Note: The library will take permissions, if you haven't already, even without calling takePermissions() explicitly. This behavior may change in future.

It's easy to toggle Flash too

```
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().toggleFlash();
```

It's a good practice to release all the resources, once you're done.

```
NoobCameraManager.getInstance().release();
```

Comment: Yes I had found this Library too, but I always get this Error Message:  (Edit: Error Message is too long for this comment -> https://pastebin.com/FwqZhxXZ )

Comment: You wouldn't If you asked User for Permission and Initiated the Library...

Comment: I init the Library via EasyFlashlight.init(this); in Constructor and ask for the following Permissions in Manifest.xml: android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.FLASHLIGHT
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.hardware.camera.flash

Comment: if(EasyFlashlight.getInstance().canAccessFlashlight) {
 //now you can interact safely with the Flashlight API
}

Comment: Because Android Studio says: "cannot resolve symbol 'canAccesFlashlight'" I'd added two Brackets so my If-Statement looks like that: if(EasyFlashlight.getInstance().canAccessFlashlight()) { EasyFlashlight.getInstance().turnOn(); } //Edit: Still cause the Error

Comment: I replaced this library in my project with the old one. Nevertheless, I received the same error. Afterwards I downloaded the official demo project of NoobCameraFlash and opened it in Android Studio. I wanted to test this project on my Wiko Rainbow Jam (Android 5.1) but I get the same bug here, too.

Is there something wrong with my phone?

Comment: wait... Your phone does have a flash right? what is the model?

Comment: Of course, my mobile phone has a camera and lamp on the back. http://de.wikomobile.com/m834-rainbow-jam (Edit: And the camera (including flash light) works with Facebook, Instagramm, etc. Apps)

Comment: The Error seems to be the same. `Bad argument passed to camera service` meaning you are doing something wrong.. I have used this library. and it works fine for me.. On the other hand you can always try using the link u mentioned in ur question.

Comment: I can't imagine I'm doing anything wrong because I downloaded and opened the example project from NoobCameraManager. This works as already mentioned, not even with my mobile phone. Tomorrow I will try to start the app on other mobile phones, because I don't have any other mobile phones available at the moment. If that doesn't help, I'll probably have to google for a long time. ; D

And once again: In normal use, the flash and camera work.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Hey Syed Ali Naqi, I was able to solve the problem with a code snippet.

Comment: Great! what was the Problem?