# Android - Switch between front and back camera while recording a video

Tags: android, android-layout, video, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to implement Custom Camera to record a video. I have followed [This sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) and it is working fine.

Now, i want to add **"Switch Camera"** functionality over a Button click. It should be able to **Switch between Front/Back Camera** even while the video is getting recorded.

Hence please help me to know if it is even possible??

**1. If yes then How??**

**2. If no then Please suggest some workaround??**

Some sample codes or links would be very helpful...

**Note :** I have been googling about it and found some StackOverFlow answers like

[Android Camera2 API switch back - front cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022845/android-camera2-api-switch-back-front-cameras)

[Android: Switch camera when button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765527/android-switch-camera-when-button-clicked)

But none of these are giving a **facility to switch the camera when the video is being recorded**.

**Please Help.**

The code is same as [This sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video). And it's the **Camera2 API**.

Comment: Not possible as `CameraCaptureSession` is connected with `CameraDevice` and front and back cameras are different devices ... you may try to record another file and then, after user stops recording, merge files with some media library

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 6):

As far as i concerned, that camera is device and [@Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) explained front and back cameras are different devices.Now let me start from first,

Some of the device has own functionality that you can switch the camera during video is recording.like **Nexus 9**. [For more detail please refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508276/in-android-is-it-possible-to-change-camera-from-front-to-back-and-still-keep).

Another way you can do by using **MediaRecorder**. You can implement like this question's answer. **[how to switch between front and back camera when using MediaRecorder android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471025/how-to-switch-between-front-and-back-camera-when-using-mediarecorder-android)**

I have no more idea about that but if you want to do then do like this:-
  1. When your record video using back camera and switch to front camera then temporary save that video in local and star with front camera.
  2. now stop the video recording then marge that both file and save as single file..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I will check the links, try the solutions and will let you know.

Comment: Sure let me know that you will get your solution or not?

Comment: I could not find a perfect solution hence i am accepting yours.

Comment: Hello. Did you managed to resolve it without saving different files and then merging them? @iMDroid

Answer (score 0):

```
camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
// Pass 0 And 1 currentCameraId
setCameraDisplayOrientation(CameraActivity.this, currentCameraId, camera);
try {

    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
camera.startPreview();
}
```

Comment: This is to open a camera and not to switch it. Please read the question again.

Comment: based on  button click pass value 0 and 1 . this answer is for switching camera and open respected camera based on 0 and 1 value.

Comment: This doesn't work in during the recording. i have already mentioned that.