# Android : How to turn flashlight on/off programmly using Camera Source Builder?

Tags: java, android, camera

i made Camera Preview using CameraSource in Android Studio

```
new CameraSource.Builder(this , detector).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build();
```

as you can see i easliy set the Auto Focus Enabled.

i was just wondering if there is an easy way to enable/disable flashlight ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this method:

```
.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH).build();
```

**Edit:**

This class was deprecated in API level 21.
Google recommends using the new android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications.

In this thread you can see how to use: [Turning on/off flash with Android camera2 API not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695149/turning-on-off-flash-with-android-camera2-api-not-working)

Comment: FLASH_MODE_TORCH is deprecated, is there any updated answer?