# setTorchMode() minimizes the app and is not turning on Flash

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have only minor experience with Android and have the following snippet:

`String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[1];
 System.out.println(cameraId);
 cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);`

which should turn on the flash on the backside camera (Ideally). This snippet is executed in an `onClickListener`. When the `cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);` gets executed, the app gets minimized (I can see its still running - not crashed) but the flash is not turned on.

I am almost exhausted after experimenting options like adding extra check whether the flash is available and all. The project is set for Jellybean+ versions of Android. The test phone is Lollipop 5.0.2.

I know this question may be a duplicate of :
[How to open device flashlight in Android N?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443836/how-to-open-device-flashlight-in-android-n)

But had exhaustively tried every option and desperately need a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mCameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String camID : mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camID);
                int lensFacing = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (lensFacing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK 
                        && cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE)) {
                    mCameraId = camID;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (mCameraId != null) {
                mCameraManager.setTorchMode(mCameraId, true);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

mCameraId will turn on back camera flash. If device has no flash hardware then mCameraId will be null and setTorchMode will not be called in the code above.