# Flashlight doesn't turn on with Camera Source

Tags: android, android-camera

**I'm accessing the camera using the SurfaceView and CameraSource and showing the image on the screen. The application also need to use the flash light. The camera view freezes when I turn on the flash light. I don't want this to happen. I don't understand why. When the flash light is on, the camera must be active at the same time. For example, taking pictures with the flash light on the phone. I am using the following codes. I'd appreciate it if you could help or indicate what caused the problem.**

*My code is working. But when I turn on the flashlight, the camera image remains attached.

> MyActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView cameraPreview;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

    ImageButton Flash_On_Button;

    private Camera cam;
    Camera.Parameters p;

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        Flash_On_Button  = findViewById(R.id.Flash_On_Button);
        Flash_On_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FlashON();          
            }
        });

        cameraPreview  = findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        CameraStart() ;
}


    private void CameraStart() {

                cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScanActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},RequestCameraPermissionID);
                            return;
                        }
                        try {
                            cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                            Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "surface Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "surface Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                        cameraSource.stop();
                        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "surface Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }


    public void FlashON(){

            try {
                if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                        PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {

                    cam = Camera.open();
                    p = cam.getParameters();

                    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    cam.setParameters(p);
                    cam.startPreview();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception flashLightOn()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can mix the deprecated `Camera` API with `CameraSource`. I can't even understand how `Camera.open()` executes, in your code, without throwing -- `CameraSource` has already opened the camera! And since it's already previewing, it's almost certainly the `startPreview()` call that freezes the screen. Try removing that. Otherwise, I don't know how to get a `Camera` from a `CameraSource`, so I can't be of much help. Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699273/android-turn-on-off-camera-flash-programatically-with-camera2).

Comment: I removed the startpreview (). But the problem continues. I need to use the Camera Source with SurfaceView to process the image on the screen.
"Camerasource.start (camerapreview.gethold is ())"
  I need to turn on the flash light while the screen is alive. I need to access the camera as a hardware and start the camera to open the flash. The image freezes and flashes when I start it. "Cam.start ()"
Thanks for your reply. @greeble31

Comment: I mean, obviously you _can_ do this; others have done it. What I'm trying to say is, you can't do it using a `CameraSource`. At least I really don't think so. You're going to need to re-architect your app to use [`Detector.detect()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector.html#detect(com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame)) instead. You're going to have to set up your own frame pipeline. You'll probably have to find a tutorial somewhere to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing the following codes:

Availability of flash light

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

Enable On/Off of the flash light, include this in your Android Manifest

```
 <!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
 <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
         android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
         android:protectionLevel="normal"
         android:label="@string/permlab_flashlight"
         android:description="@string/permdesc_flashlight" />
```

To turn on camera flashlight

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

To turn off camera flashlight

```
cam.stopPreview();
cam.release();
```

The complete discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-front-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my problem is that the camera doesn't display when I turn on the Flash light. I already have a code to turn on the flash light. The answer is exactly the same as my code. Thank you for your reply.