# Turning camera flash on and off in a loop (stroboscopic) without interrupting camera preview

Tags: android, flash, opencv, camera, opencv3.0

Is it possible to turn on and off **stroboscopic** flash in android without interrupting the camera preview?

Comment: [Related reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android) but I'm not entirely sure if this solves the problem or not, there is a lot in that answer.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help. What i'm doing is turning flash on and off (stroboscopic light) with face detection. I was able to do the stroboscopic light using task timer but when I choose to set the flash into stroboscopic, other codes are ignored. What I am trying to find is how to make the work as one. face detection in while stroboscopic light is active.