# How to end a loop with a click in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming. I am working on an app which will make the flashlight blink when the button is pressed and turn it off when the button is pressed again.

Currently I am stuck in an infinite loop where I can't understand how to give it a command to end the loop when the button is pressed again.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    camera = Camera.open(); //opening camera hardware
    params = camera.getParameters(); //getting parameters

    //finding elements
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    //accessed within inner class at onClick , so it must be declared final

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isOn){
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                isOn=false;
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnoff);
            } else {
                while(!isOn) {
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnon);
                isOn=true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is running the process (the loop) in the main thread which causes the UI to be blocked. You have to remember that you **must not** block the UI in android.

So what you need to do is create another thread for your operations. You can do it using [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or whatever method you know for multi-threading.

What will happen is, in your `onClickListener`, you will only set the value of `isOn`. The process (other things inside the `if-else` statement) must be implemented on another thread.

Comment: Another improvement would be to _not_ use spin-wait (while{ Thread.Sleep} ) but some means of scheduled trigger. For example a scheduled Executor or a Timer ...

Comment: Thanks... I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Since camera light on and off logic is too long to fill in the event handler,you should put them outside of it to keep it clean.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isOn){
               turnOff();
            } else {
               turnOn();
            }
    }  

      private void turnOn() {
        // ... logic on turn on
        isOn = true;
      }

      private void turnOff() {
        // ...logic on turn off
        isOn = false;
      }
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android) post on how to turn camera light on and off programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code read:

```
isOn = true;
while(isOn) {
    // some code
}
```

instead of :

```
while(!isOn) {
    // some code
}
isOn = true;
```