# How to record video as well as turn on flash light at same time?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to record a video with a flash light to be on to make focus on the capture.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I'm not able to start camera and flash at same time. Not able to show the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-turn-onoff-camera-ledflashlight-in-android/

Comment: I know how to turn on Camera/Flash but can you please tell me how to turn on camera+flash light at same time???

Comment: Have you seen the links I share?

Comment: Yes but there is either of flash or camera to be turn on want both at a time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104989/discussion-between-patidarnikunj-and-nouman-ghaffar).

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Check if device has camera

```
  boolean   hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
                    .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
  Camera camera = Camera.open();
  Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
```

to turn on the flash

```
  params = camera.getParameters();
  params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
  camera.setParameters(params);
  camera.startPreview();
```

to turn off the flash

```
params = camera.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(params);
camera.stopPreview();
```

in that case you can use SurfaceView
add this to your xml

```
<SurfaceView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

then in activity

```
surfaceview=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
surfaceholder=surfaceview.getHolder();
surfaceholder.addCallback(this);
surfaceholder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceholder);

            camera.startPreview();

            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
```

Comment: I already know this but I want to turn on camera as well as flash light at same time