# Camera flash not turning off

Tags: android, android-camera

So I'm working on an Activity where you're supposed to take a picture and then uploading it to a Parse server.

Everything is working fine except for the flash mode; turning it on works but turning it off doesn't work.

This is my code for turning the flash on:

```
private void turnOnFlash() {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        isFlashOn = true;

        // Show the flash mode in a Toast.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash mode: " + camera.getParameters().getFlashMode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Changing button image.
        imgFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_white_48dp);
    }
}
```

This is my code for turning the flash off:

```
private void turnOffFlash() {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        isFlashOn = false;

        // Show the flash mode in a Toast.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash mode: " + camera.getParameters().getFlashMode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Changing button image.
        imgFlash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_off_white_48dp);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The Toast that shows the flash mode shows `Flash mode: off` when the `turnOffFlash()` method is called, but the flash remains on.

Comment: Probably your camera object reference is not set properly (still null), hence returning immediately.

Comment: @SachinGadagi I just added an extra Toast in the `if (camera == null || params == null)` and it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I suggest use this link to turn on or off flash [turn on or off flash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069503/4198372)

Comment: @HamidrezaShokouhi The problem I'm having with that method is that it turns off the camera preview, which I want to keep on.

Comment: @HamidrezaShokouhi That still doesn't help the fact that the camera preview stops when turning off the flash.