# how to use flash of android phone "without" using camera api

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using samsung phone with lollipop android , I has got a flash button on the notification curtain which turns on and off flash light

My company has installed an app on my phone which do not allows the use of camera,so whenever i run a torch or flashlight app it says camera use denied and hence flash doesn't turns on , but the button given in notification curtain of lollipop still works and flash glows ,means it is not using camera api,How ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: @AmanGrover Its not duplicate because every answer in that link is using camera api.

Comment: Maybe that setting (since it's built in the ROM) has higher privileges than the policy your company has set?

Comment: The flashlight quick settings tile uses the CameraManager.