# How to make an Android flashlight blink when device show result on screen?

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight

If I want to make the device flashlight blink when device show result on screen.

I try this code for blinking the flash, but it is not blinking.

some parts of MainActivity.java

```
public void onResult(String result) {
String tres = "\n";
String myString = "0101010101";
long blinkDelay = 50;
try {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject j1 = j.getJSONObject("status");
    int j2 = j1.getInt("code");
    if(j2 == 0){
        JSONObject metadata = j.getJSONObject("metadata");
        if (metadata.has("custom_files")) {
            JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("custom_files");
            for(int i=0; i<musics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i); 
                String title = tt.getString("title");
                tres = tres + (i+1) + ".  Title: " + title + "\n";
            }
           //Flash Light blink
            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                } else {
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                }
                try {
                Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        tres = result;
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    tres = result;
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mResult.setText(tres);
}
```

permission of Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with Flashlight permissions in manifest.

I am suggesting you to check suggested link for flashlight on/off: [Flashlight On/Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android/6069503#6069503)