# Why is the camera flash not turning on and the CameraAccessException class is underlined red?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to make a torchlight app but I am not able to turn it on properly. I have used the following logic to turn it on. Please let me know where I am going wrong. When I run this on my android phone it runs properly but the flashlight doesn't start.

```
if (count[0] == 0) {
    count[0] = 1;
    ((TransitionDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).startTransition(3000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        String cameraId = null; // Usually back camera is at 0 position.
        try {
            cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);   //Turn ON
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} else {
    count[0] = 0;
    ((TransitionDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).reverseTransition(3000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        CameraManager camManager1 = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        String cameraId = null; // Usually back camera is at 0 position.
        try {
            cameraId = camManager1.getCameraIdList()[0];
            camManager1.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);   //Turn ON
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the version of Android are you running it on?

Comment: running it on a KitKat phone.

Comment: Are you aware of what `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {` does?

Comment: ow I understand that it should be 16..but then some classess are failing

Comment: thanks it helped!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written is fully functional on Android Marshmallow+.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
```

This line checks for what version of Android you are running the app on. It executes the code within the `if` block only on Android version 6+ (API level 23+).

You need to add the `else` part with an older way of turning the flashlight on like this method: [How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14084688/1468093)