# Is there any way to access the Torch light status in Android. I want to check whether the flash light is in ON state or OFF state programatically

Tags: android, flashlight

Is it possible to know the state of Flash light in Android. I want to run a loop, before which I would like to know whether the Flash Light of the device is in ON/OFF state.

Comment: Please find this LInk.. I hope it will clear all your doubt.
[Link to Handle Flash Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: @Shylesh try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android).it might help you..

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati the above link helps the user to **Turn On and Off** the Flash. I want my code to **Check the current state** of the Flash. For instatnce, I Switch on the flash light from the notification bar shortcut. Then I open my app and press on **TEST** button, It Should show **"ON"** status.

Answer (score 3):

Register the `torchCallback`

```
        Handler handler =  new Handler(getMainLooper());

        CameraManager mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        CameraManager.TorchCallback torchCallback = new CameraManager.TorchCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onTorchModeChanged(String cameraId, boolean enabled){
                super.onTorchModeChanged(cameraId, enabled);
                boolean currentTorchState = enabled;
            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            mCameraManager.registerTorchCallback(torchCallback, handler);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can not get the STATE of Flash Light.

For that you have to manage the state manually like,

```
boolean isFlashStateOn = false;
.
.
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (isFlashStateOn ) {
        turnOffFlashLight();
        isFlashStateOn = false;
    } else {
        turnOnFlashLight();
        isFlashStateOn = true;
    }
}
```