# Java Need to enable flash with inbuild camera while image capturing

Tags: java, android

Trying to enable flash while capturing image with camera through intent, but when camera opens flash is turning off.

Is there a way to do this functionality.

Comment: checkout this, is that your answer? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585201/17219280](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585201/17219280)

Answer (score 2):

There are no documented and supported extras for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to demand that a camera app do anything specific with the flash. And, even if there were, camera apps could ignore those extras.

If you need that level of control over the camera, use CameraX or a third-party camera library and embed the camera usage within your app, rather than delegating it via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.