# How to turn on/off flashlight when camera in use?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, torch, flashlight

I'm creating an app that uses the camera and flashlight on android, the problem is that I need to turn flashlight on while the camera is running, I looked at some of the answers but none of them could help me, please help me?!

[How to turn on front flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-front-flash-light-programmatically-in-android) this answer don't work for me, because in this answer is to turn on front flashlight, I need to turn the back flash on while the camera is running

Comment: are you using a library? which one? show some code

Comment: I've used [ https://github.com/LucemAnb/Android-Text-Scanner ] this library for camera

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn on front flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-to-turn-on-front-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: This answer is to turn on the front flashlight, I need to turn the back flashlight on while the camera is running

Comment: @HusniddinMadaminov The question may specifically mention the front camera, but the accepted answer is agnostic.

Comment: I'm using Camera2 and have the exact problem(

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

```
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), cameraCaptureCallback, cameraBackgroundHandler)
```

So, firstly you should set up `FLASH_MODE` request, and then you update the current session with that request.