# androidx camera2 video capture with flash

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, androidx, android-camera2

I am looking to use camera2 for image and video capture. I found that for image capture I can use the method `.setFlashMode(flash_type)` but the video capture object does not have this.

```
CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    String cameraId = null; 
    try {
        cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);   //Turn ON
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748375/6672466) method where I would turn on the flash before the video capture but was hit with an error which was due to the camera already being in use.

So, I am wondering, is this even possible in androidx yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution over at the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177449107) for androidx.camera which seems to work.

```java
if (flash_type == ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON)
    videoCapture.getCamera().getCameraControl().enableTorch(true);
```

Any then do the opposite when stopping the video capture.

Answer (score 1):

Video capture in CameraX is not yet even an alpha-version public API,  so it's very possible it doesn't yet support flash control.

Comment: I found a solution that is not part of the API in the same way as a camera but it is part of the VideoCapture class.