# Sony Ericsson SDK on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, sony

I need to get the Sony ericsson sdk from their website on my eclipse so I can continue with my app to control the LEDs for the Xperia S device.

I downloaded the SDK and have installed it successfully , but I still cant import anything on my Eclipse project that i need from the Sony SDK.

Can someone enlighten me here?

Sony dev page where i got my SDK from: http://developer.sonymobile.com/cws/devworld/search-downloads/docstools/sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the purpose for you to download the SDK you mentioned above.

In order to control LED (I assume flash used with the camera is what you mean by LED), you don't need any of these SDK's. 
Check this out: [Android Camera Flash Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294621/android-camera-flash-control)
and also this [How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)

You can control that LED by simple Android API's. With respect to your comment about Live Ware Manager above, it is an application, not an SDK. Although there is another SDK used to create applications for Live View but it doesn't seem like you have anything to do with Live View.

If you need to know more about Smart SDk or EDK sdk, please visit these links: http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/technology/smart-extras/smart-extension-sdk

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/technology/android/edk/overview

Let me know if I didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Android SDK and ADT in Eclipse, per usual. In Eclipse, select Window > Android SDK Manager.  Let it search for updates, etc. When it finally populates the list, under Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10), you should see an entry for Sony Xperia Extensions EDK 2.0.  Check the box to the right of that and then click "Install packages..."
[image]

Comment: Hello, that allows me to instal only that SDK, I now need the liveware SDK which is not present on Eclipse, how can I import that SDK into eclise?

Answer (score -1):

please  instal google usb driver and download sdk 
instal pc suite  sony instal mobile  to pc  and  automoatic download driver

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk-manual-installation-kit/
Sony Add-on SDK (manual installation kit)
Sony Add-on SDK to be used for manual installation. You should also get the documentation kit.
Download Sony Add-on SDK (manual installation kit) (159 MB)